my "Restricted Groups" GPO which add "Domain Users" to "Remote Desktop Users Group" doesn't apply to the local group
I've setup this GPO :

capture of the "Group Policy Results" on a given machine from "Group Policy Management" tool
But the local group stays empty after rebooting / starting a session / calling gpupdate :

capture of "Local Users And Groups" tool on the same machine
And so the users allowed to use RDP stays empty (until I edit it locally) :

capture of RDP user list
I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

there is no conflicting GPO
there is no filtering of the GPO, it applies to every authenticated users
the "Allow Log On Through Remote Services" policy is left untouched, so default to "Administrators + Remote Desktop Users Group"

additional informations

The GPO is set up as follow :


capture of the GPO "Setup Remote Desktop Users Group" settings

Content of GptTmpl.inf matching the current policy (edited the domain name, even though it doesn't really matter...)

[Unicode]
Unicode=yes
[Version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"
Revision=1
[Group Membership]
***\Domain Users__Memberof = *S-1-5-32-555
***\Domain Users__Members =

additional informations (gpscv.log)
from gpsvc.log, the policy seems to be processed. The log is quiet long, I may have missed an information...
GPSVC(174c.3720) 14:37:48:868 ProcessGPO(Machine):  GPSVC(174c.3720) 14:37:48:868 ProcessGPO(Machine):  ==============================
GPSVC(174c.3720) 14:37:48:868 ProcessGPO(Machine):  Searching <cn={33591F18-FA1D-4E9F-807F-2B9EAF614135},cn=policies,cn=system,DC=ad,DC=***,DC=tv>
GPSVC(174c.3720) 14:37:48:869 ProcessGPO(Machine):  Machine has access to this GPO.
GPSVC(174c.3720) 14:37:48:869 ProcessGPO(Machine):  Found common name of:  <{33591F18-FA1D-4E9F-807F-2B9EAF614135}>
GPSVC(174c.3720) 14:37:48:870 ProcessGPO(Machine):  GPO passes the filter check.
GPSVC(174c.3720) 14:37:48:870 ProcessGPO(Machine):  Found functionality version of:  2
GPSVC(174c.3720) 14:37:48:870 ProcessGPO(Machine):  Found file system path of:  <\\ad.***.tv\SysVol\ad.***.tv\Policies\{33591F18-FA1D-4E9F-807F-2B9EAF614135}>
GPSVC(174c.3720) 14:37:48:877 ProcessGPO(Machine):  Found display name of:  <Setup Remote Desktop>
GPSVC(174c.3720) 14:37:48:877 ProcessGPO(Machine):  Found machine version of:  GPC is 52, GPT is 52
GPSVC(174c.3720) 14:37:48:878 ProcessGPO(Machine):  Found flags of:  0
GPSVC(174c.3720) 14:37:48:878 ProcessGPO(Machine):  Found extensions:  [{827D319E-6EAC-11D2-A4EA-00C04F79F83A}{803E14A0-B4FB-11D0-A0D0-00A0C90F574B}]
GPSVC(174c.3720) 14:37:48:879 ProcessGPO(Machine):  ==============================

Thanks for your help,
Paul Jacamon

You need to provide the policy details. Where is it linked?

The policy is inside a "Setup Remote Desktop Group" GPO, linked to the root of the "forest" (We don't have a huge domain, so we actually don't need a lot of specific Organisation Units). Does it answers the question ?

Furthermore, the 1st capture is from the "results", so only applied policies are shown

Open the policy in GPMC, take screenshots of the settings and group memberships that you have configured. Also find the policy folder in SYSVOL by the guid, and get the text inf ini file that contains the group memberships.

I've added a screenshot of the GPO settings and the content of the GptTmpl.inf file found in the policy folder, thanks for your help !

Enable Group Policy environment debug logging and check the log file to confirm it is picking up the group memberships. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-directory-services-team/a-treatise-on-group-policy-troubleshooting-8211-now-with-gpsvc/ba-p/400304

The GPO setup you have is wrong. The policy needs to be for the Remote Desktop Users group, not Domain Users.

I believe both direction should work. I initially set the « remote contains user » direction, and tried, among other things, the other way, « users are part of remote », but neither work. Examples of both methods can be found on the net.

And the logging? Did that "work"?

An example can be found here, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1659509/group-policy-enable-remote-desktop-on-pcs-select-a (step 11-12 of the accepted answer)

I’ll try to retrieve logs asap, thanks for the tip

small update : we will setup a new domain on win server 2022...

As Greg Askew said in a comment, your policy is wrong.
You should configure the policy to act on the "Remote Desktop Users" group and add "DOMAINNAME\Domain Users" to it as a member, while instead you are trying to do the exact opposite.

This is true and please don’t link the GPO to the root of the forest/domain. Configuring Restricted Groups incorrectly can create significant security concerns. You might consider creating a new security group, adding only the users who need to login using RDP, and adding the group to Remote Desktop Users. Service accounts and other non-authorized accounts should not be allowed to login using RDP so you do not want to use Domain Users as the group to add to “Remote Desktop Users”.
